# What is the effect of larger dopant concentrations in a pn-junction diode?

Tags: pn-junction

When we increase the concentration of dopants on both the sides of a pn-junction diode, how do the I-V characteristics change? In particular what is the effect on breakdown voltage and forward knee voltage?

I guess that breakdown occurs earlier and the knee voltage is also reduced.